# Issue with Spring Boot Validation with version 2.5.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven, validation

I am fairly new to Spring Boot and it's various libraries. I am particularly trying Validation. I have added Validation annotations to UserDto class. When I send createUser request with invalid email, I get success. None of the validations work.
I have tried using Hibernate-Validator dependancy as well.
See below the code.

The UserDto class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class UserDto {
    
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=5)
    @Max(value=10)
    private String name;
    
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=3)
    @Max(value=50)
    private String password;
    
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    public UserDto(String name, String password, String email) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The UserCotroller:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.user.test.dto.UserDto;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto, Errors errors){
        
        System.out.println(userDto.toString());
        System.out.println(errors.toString());
        String response = "success";    
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        
    }

}
```

Driver Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.user</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the Postman Request, which gives "success".

{
"name": "Username",
"password":"username@123",
"email":"username"
}

Answer (score 0):

I could find two issues in your code:

1. The @Min/@Max annotations are for numeric values, to set the range of numeric values (not the number of strings); so these do not work for Strings. Please remove them and find alternatives (e.g. @Size).
2. You need to map the userDto object to the model in your controller with the @ModelAttribute annotation.

**Controller** (further edited to accommodate different responses)

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto,Errors errors){

            System.out.println(userDto.toString());
            System.out.println(errors.toString());
            if (errors.hasErrors()) {
              return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Errors exist");
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
        }

}
```

**UserDto**

```
public class UserDto {

 @NotNull
 @Size(min=5, max= 10)
 private String name;

 @NotNull
 @Size(min=3, max= 50)
 private String password;

 @Email
 private String email;

// rest of the code
}
```

**Tests for controller**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserControllerTest {


    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    UserController userController;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    }


    @Test
    void emailInvalid() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/users").param("name", "uname")
                        .param( "password", "LongPasswordHere")
                        .param( "email", "email")).andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Errors exist")));
    }

    @Test
    void emailValid() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/users").param("name", "uname")
                        .param( "password", "LongPasswordHere")
                        .param( "email", "email@gmail.com")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Success")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did these changes you mentioned. Although after adding @ModelAttribute annotation to method, it looks like all the fields are captured as null. 
UserDto [name=null, password=null, email=null]. Why must this be happening?
Although these is an error, I get "success" message in return. Here is the error message I get:
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'userDto' on field 'password': rejected value [null]
Field error in object 'userDto' on field 'name': rejected value [null]

Comment: You get success message because you always return ResponseEntity.ok() (even if there are errors).
I can't say why you get null values, maybe something with the request you are doing?
I will add a modified version of the controller and two tests that do post requests and verify the controller is working correctly